# Is it OK to ask a question immediately after a comma?

Tags: punctuation

I rarely see people do that but I have found the usage fit my writing style.

e.g.

I don't have access to the internet right now **, could** you handle the task for me please?

-thanks

Comment: One is a statement, the other is a question.  The statement should end in a period. The question should start with a capital C.

Comment: A semicolon would be better than a comma.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question, but the sentence sounds odd. As soon as I read your question, the concept of Relative Clauses tugged upon my mind. Upon further searching, I found out that your sentence can be better presented with a co-ordinating conjunction. In this case, it might be better off as:

> I don't have access to the internet right now, ***so*** could you handle the task for me?

This sounds about fine. Hopefully the grammar teachers can verify!

Anyways, check out Relative Clauses subject, might help.